# How to enable external microphone in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

I have a headset with a built-in microphone. Ubuntu detects the headset just fine but it doesn't detect the microphone attached.

The only option for sound input is the internal microphone. I've tried a few solutions I found in the forums but they didn't work.

I've tried using the hdajackretask; all it did was rename the internal microphone into microphone. The command used to install `linux-backports-modules-alsa-generic` does not work either and says:

> unable to locate package error

My sound card is recognized by the system. It's an HDA Intel PCH and the chip is Realtek ALC255. Edit: My external microphone works on Windows 10 (dual-boot). Laptop is an Acer E14 E5-475G-30KY. Only one jack but works for both input and output.

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio [8086:9d70] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio [1025:110f]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl

$ arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], 
device 0: ALC255 Analog [ALC255 Analog]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

$ pactl list short sources
0   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo.monitor  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
1   alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo   module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
2   alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo.echo-cancel   module-echo-cancel.c    s16le 1ch 32000Hz   SUSPENDED
3   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo.echo-cancel.monitor  module-echo-cancel.c    s16le 1ch 32000Hz   SUSPENDED
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I forgot to mention that on Windows 10 (dual-boot), the external microphone works perfectly. The jack I have is a combined port for both input and output device.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of the terminal commands `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio`, `arecord -l`, and `pactl list short sources`? Please also make sure that the relevant audio input channels in `alsamixer` (terminal) or `gnome-alsamixer` (GUI) have their volume turned up and aren’t muted. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFoerster the requested info has been edited into question. And also only the "Beep" block is the only one on mute in alsamixer.

Comment: So I've been searching here and ubuntuforums.com and found out that this is a common problem but no one has a definitive solution for it. Usually affects laptops which have a combo 3.5mm jack. Either the external microphone does not appear as a valid input in the sound options or it just doesn't work. I guess it's safe to say that this problem cannot be answered.